# Variable not being to view by controller

Tags: php, yii, variable-assignment

**Controller Action**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new News;
    $contentModel = new NewsContent;
    // if I do a `var_dump( $contentModel )` here, I get variable dump correctly

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'contentModel'=>$contentModel,
    ));
}
```

**View**

```
<?php var_dump( $model ); // dumps the variable correctly ?> 
<?php var_dump( $contentModel ); // dumps null ?>
```

---

So why is `contentModel` not being passed to the view and `model` is?

Note that I have verified that I am referencing the correct view. I have tested this by not passing the `model` variable and seeing a `null` dumped in place of original variable dump in the view

Comment: Are you in the create view or in the _form view?

Comment: Sigh! That was it. I spent over an hour on this, and the issue turned out to be right between by eyes.

Comment: It's a common error at the beginning :)

Comment: Yes, shows that I am new to Yiiing. Would you like to post that as an answer so I can accept it. Might help out other fellows looking for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `actionCreate` and `actionUpdate` render the `create` and `update` views respectively, but both views also partially render the `_form` view, where basically everything is displayed.

Also, take a look at this, it helped me a lot when I was getting to know Yii. [Understanding the view rendering flow](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/)

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the comma (",")

```
$this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'contentModel'=>$contentModel
));
```

Comment: You are not familiar with basic PHP syntax, I'm afraid.